# Need Google Geocoding to return City name in English

Tags: php, geocoding

I have this code for requesting google to correct the typed in address, and need it to return the English name for the city:

```
function gmap_query_xml($in_address) {
  $base_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&region=US&language=en&key=". KEY;
  $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($in_address);
  return simplexml_load_file($request_url);
}
```

Then,

```
$xml = gmap_query_xml($in_address);
```

And finally to get the city name:

```
if ($xml) {
  $city = (string) $xml->Response->Placemark->AddressDetails->Country->AdministrativeArea->SubAdministrativeArea->Locality->LocalityName;
}
```

This returns the **correct city name**, **BUT!** it's represented in the native language. Try Rome - you get Roma, try Kiev and you will get Киев.

How this can be solved? Thank!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of a chaos in that regard. See [this list of Google Geocoding API bug reports](http://www.devcomments.com/Bug-Report-default-language-behavior-difference-between-geocoder-at241613.htm).

You are using the old V2 API.

According to [this post](http://www.devcomments.com/Bug-Report-default-language-behavior-difference-between-geocoder-at229546.htm) and my own tests, the new [V3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rome&sensor=false&language=en
```

is more sensitive to the `language` parameter and translates locality names correctly. I get correct results for `language=en` (Rome), `language=de` (Rom) and even `language=fi` (Rooma)!

However, V3 serves its geocoding results in a different format so you would have to change your parsing considerably (Due to the way `addressComponents` is structured now, this bugged the heck out of me too).